# Close Fancybox popup after successful form submition

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created a fancy popup for small form and i want the popup should be removed after submission of form. Please help me with the correct solution.

```
<form id="form" method="post" name="legal_cust" action="javascript:formSubmit();">
// all stuff here with html form
</form>
```

and i am calling the javascript function after this i want to close fancybox from javascript function.
`

```
<script>
 if(!check_cookie) 
        {
            beginNewsletterForm();
            <?php Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('popup-shown', 'true', 5);?>
        }        
    });
    function beginNewsletterForm () 
    {
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'width': '600',
            'modal':'true',
            'height': '600',
            'padding': '0px',
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'autoScale': true,
            'autoSize': false,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'type': 'inline'
        });
        jQuery("#bdate-popup").trigger('click');
    }
</script>
```

`

i want to write something which will remove fancy popup

```
<script>
function formSubmit()
{
//something to remove popup
}
</script>
```

Comment: From the documentation: `$.fancybox.close( true );`

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$.fancybox.close();
```